# Удалит ли std::map::erase элемент из памяти (указатель), а не только из мэпа?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

У меня есть std::map<const char*,Node*>, вызовет ли std::map::erase("ченибудь")

```
delete node["ченибудь"];
```

для каждого удаляемого из мэпа нода или мне надо это делать самому? Просто документация пишет: "This effectively reduces the container size by the number of elements removed, **calling each element's destructor**", означает ли это что для указателей будет вызван delete? Логично предположить, что нет, так как в контейнере может хранится и не указатель, например int, но что тогда означает "calling each element's destructor"? и кто-нибудь пробовал на практике? ЗЫ компилер VC хотя по идее реализация не должна различаться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, не удалит.
Указатель, после своего уничтожения, не освобождает память, на которую он ссылается.

Comment: Логично это предполагать, так как в контейнере может хранится и не указатель, например int, но что тогда означает "calling each element's destructor"?

Comment: Про "calling each element's destructor" - Вы храните указатели, будут вызваны деструкторы указателей. Если в контейнере храниться int, то будет вызван деструктор int, что просто означает очистку памяти, которую этот int занимает.

Comment: @fogbit

- Здесь вопрос, скорее, заключается в том, как идеологически понимать "деструктор для примитивных типов вроде `int`". То есть, по сути *(поскольку он не имеет смыла)* - либо от них нужно отказываться, либо думать о таких деструкторах как о `no-op` деструкторах.

Comment: - Стандарт принимает здесь вариант номер 2 `[C++03 12.4.15]` и сделано это для того, что не задумываться о наличии деструктора у произвольного типа `T` при написании шаблонного кода. **Деструктор есть всегда.**

> The notation for explicit call of a destructor can be used for any scalar type name. Allowing this makes it possible to write code without having to know if a destructor exists for a given type.

Answer (score 2):

Удалит указатели, а выделенную память - нет. Лучше используйте std::string вместо char* и какой-нибудь smart-pointer для Node. Например, так:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr< Node > NodePtr;
std::map< std::string, NodePtr> MyMap;
```

Comment: QMap (QT-аналог) не удаляет сам указатель, например и не считает это неправильным

Comment: Указатель - это просто адрес на память. В данном случае он и будет возвращен системе, а память, на которую он указывает - нет. Не может быть, чтобы QMap не разрушал своих элементов. Как вы это определили?

Comment: удалит как-бы ячейку памяти где хранится указатель в QMap-е, но не область памяти куда указывает указатель, то есть если храним указатели и хотим уничтожить элемент, надо будет делать:

                delete nodes.value("ключ");
                nodes.remove("ключ");//аналог erase

Comment: Лучше возложить контроль над памятью самой строки подходящему классу, такому как std::string или QString. Они специально для этого и были придуманы, чтобы избавить программиста от рутинной работы там, где это не нужно.